# CustomControl with a ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, custom-controls

I'm having troubles creating a custom control with a `ComboBox`.
This is my simple code:

```
public class MyComboBox : Control
{
    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ItemsSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(MyComboBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));




    public string DisplayMemberPath
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DisplayMemberPath.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberPathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayMemberPath", typeof(string), typeof(MyComboBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));





    public string SelectedValuePath
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedValuePathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedValuePathProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedValuePath.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValuePathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValuePath", typeof(string), typeof(MyComboBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));





    public object SelectedValue
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValue", typeof(object), typeof(MyComboBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));




    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedIndexProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedIndexProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedIndex.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedIndexProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedIndex", typeof(int), typeof(MyComboBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));



    static MyComboBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyComboBox)));
    }
}
```

and this is its Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyComboBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="MyComboBox" />
                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                              SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                              DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=DisplayMemberPath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                              SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=SelectedValuePath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}">
                    </ComboBox>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

To test it, I made a simple WPF application with this MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Numbers}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                  SelectedValuePath="Value"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Number, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="{Binding Path=Number, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

        <local:MyComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyNumbers}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                          SelectedValuePath="Value"
                          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MyNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="{Binding Path=MyNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and this ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _number;
    public int Number
    {
        get { return _number; }
        set
        {
            _number = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Number");
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, int> Numbers { get; set; }

    private int _myNumber;
    public int MyNumber
    {
        get { return _myNumber; }
        set
        {
            _myNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyNumber");
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, int> MyNumbers { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Numbers = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            { "One", 1 },
            { "Two", 2 },
            { "Three", 3 }
        };
        Number = 1;

        MyNumbers = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            { "Four", 4 },
            { "Five", 5 },
            { "Six", 6 }
        };
        MyNumber = 4;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler e = PropertyChanged;
        if (e != null)
        {
            e(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

When I start it, my custom control has a red border and the output Window of Visual Studio signal this error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert '[Four, 4]' from type 'KeyValuePair`2' to type 'System.Int32' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: Int32Converter cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object value)
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)'
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value '[Four, 4]' (type 'KeyValuePair`2'). BindingExpression:Path=MyNumber; DataItem='ViewModel' (HashCode=55591935); target element is 'MyComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedValue' (type 'Object') NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: Int32Converter cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)
   at MS.Internal.Data.ObjectTargetConverter.ConvertBack(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
```

The problem disappear when I remove the property SelectedIndex from the Generic.xaml, but I need it because I want that who will use my control, can have the same basic functionality of a ComboBox.
Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Is there a reason for you to create a combobox from scratch and not expanding/using the existing one?

Comment: This is only a part of a custom control that I would like to build. I take only the part that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution by myself.
The problem is on the default value I inserted for SelectedIndex: it must be -1 and not 0.

Answer (score 0):

At first it seemed to me your problem is in SelectedValue. In you VM it has type of int, but WPF expects it to be KeyValuePair. The type of the collection's item.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyNumbers}" // KeyValuePair
     DisplayMemberPath="Key" 
     SelectedValuePath="Value"
     SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MyNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" // int
```

Then I realized my mistake that SelectedItem has to be of KeyValuePair type.
Error message looks as WPF does not look through the items' property given by the SelectedValuePath but tries to conver it explicitly to KeyValue pair. That is not documented behavior.

Comment: Moreover, if you select a value from MyComboBox, everything begins to work fine.

Comment: So the problem is just with VS's designer? At runtime everything works fine?

Comment: No the problem is when you launch the application. The red border is visible until someone changes the combobox value.